# Chandelier installation and switch wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light-fixture, multiway-switch

[image][image][image][Chandelier installed, New Duplex switch--Done!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJoXK.jpg)[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8P8.jpg)
--(ignore switch on left for outdoor light)I have four recessed ceiling lights controlled by two three-way switches in my kitchen. I want to add a chandelier and would like to replace one of the three-way switches with a duplex switch(so I don't have to install a larger box) so the chandelier can be turned ON/OFF separately from the existing recessed lights. Can I grab power for the chandelier from the existing three-way switch? How would this be wired? I'm in the USA(NYC).

Comment: Depends on how it is currently wired. Can you show how many and which wires you have at the three-way switch you want to upgrade?

Comment: Hi Jeffery, I will look at the switch in question and then report. I would like to be able to snake a bx cable from the chandelier's new mounting box to the  box where the single switch currently is and replaced it with a double switch.

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: @Ken understood exactly what I was asking. His answers and schematic helped me to achieve exactly what I wanted to do.. How do I post pictures?

Comment: You can post pictures to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and link them here

Comment: Chandelier installed, New Duplex switch- Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key for you will be finding a double switch that has a 3 way and a one way, seeing as you want to eliminate the need for changing out your box - assumption here is that you have an existing installation with drywall already in place. 
There is another factor at play though - NEC CODE requirements for how many wires you can put into that existing box. - How much space - you can't just stuff more wires just because you might have a wire hole to feed them into.

However installing a bigger box is really not that hard in this situation as some newer boxes have the box mounting screws internally - not on the outside where it would be difficult to mount in an existing installation (and yes they are screws - quite nifty for about $3.00 USA).

Your wiring might look something like this below.

[image: 3Way and Chandeliers]

**Below you will find an example of the SMART box by Madison Electric**

In your situation this makes perfect sense to use.}
The Tabs for studs - if you don't need / use them they are removable...

[image: Madison Electric 3 Gang SMART box]

Comment: Thanks Ken! I will search for this type of switch 1 / 3 way. Do they make this type of box in metal, plastic is not typically used in NYC.

Comment: I just found that one of the major manufacturers does offer single pole / 3-way combo switches!

Comment: It is a special material similar to a plastic. I don't think they make them in metal. I am not sure why they would not use it in NYC. I don't know if there is a special city code requiring metal boxes or not ( I doubt there would be - but then again it is NYC; also NYC has a lot of OLD construction;not like they are building new neighborhoods. If you are in a large building like a condo unit it might be codified to be all metal. I just don't know NYC electrical code - for that you can contact the City building code department and ask them if there is a requirement that the box be metal.

Comment: @Gary see my comment above.

Comment: Ken, Thanks for all your help with this. The hot source is connected to both commons on the 3-way SW1 and single pole SW1 using a jumper?

Comment: @Gary Your 3-way has one common screw (typically black), Line in (HOT) connects there on SW1 (you should verify that it is hot - no matter what switch position) With Circuit Breaker Off (no power) Connect your (BLACK) jumper wire (12 or 14 gauge)  from that common to the bottom end of your 1-Way switch. Your neutral and ground from the chandelier should tie in to the neutral and ground in this box.

Comment: How do i post pictures here?

Comment: @Gary to add picture on your post - edit your post. So sign in , select edit right underneath your post. When the editing window comes up there will be a toolbar , on the tool bar an insert picture icon will be there - click that , a  popup window will appear ; drag and drop a picture from your computer on the popup window - or click the popup window and a file browser will appear.

Comment: see after pics above!

Comment: @Gary - I guess you are all set . If my answer provided you with what you needed - just click the checkbox under the arrows to mark it as the answer.